# Model value is not reflected completely in UI - Angular js

Tags: angularjs

I have a method to save an object. That object is added to an array after its saved. The object has many properties . So, before adding the object to an array I am modifying few properties. Few of them don't reflect in UI .

Code :

HomeController.js

```
 $scope.MainArray=[];
 $scope.newItem={};
```

AdjustmentController.js

```
$scope.Save = function(item){

    $scope.newItem={};

    var promiseObj= $http.post('My_Url',{expectedItem: item});

    promiseObj.success(function(data,status){

        $scope.newItem.Id= data;
        $scope.newItem.dataList= item.dataList;
        $scope.newItem.LatestComment = item.LatestComment;
        $scope.newItem.CreatedDate = item.CreatedDate;

        if($scope.MainArray.length==0){
            $scope.MainArray.push($scope.newItem);
        }
        else{
            $scope.MainArray.unshift($scope.newItem);
        }

    })

}
```

HTML :

```
 <body ng-controller="HomeController">

   <div ng-controller="AdjustmentController">

     <div ng-repeat="item in MainArray ">

     <!-- This past is not updated -->
     <span>{{item.LatestComment}}</span>
     <span>{{item.CreatedDate}}</span>

     <!-- This past is updated -->
     <span>{{item.DataList[0].text}}</span>
     <span>{{item.DataList[1].text}}</span>
     <span>{{item.DataList[2].text}}</span>
     <span>{{item.DataList[3].text}}</span>

     </div>

   </div>

 </body>
```

The value is changes if I console and see. But in UI it updated only few values and `LatestComment` and `CreatedDate` is not updated.

I have also tried using `$scope.$apply()` , but it did not work.

Comment: Please include the relevant HTML code, along with the use case which should cause the value to be updated.

Comment: Where is your html code? and you need to initialize variable inside your controller first then after you can over write in your save function.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize variable **$scope.MainArray** when controller loads, then after you need to just over write it when it will needed to save.

In your controller define variable like this :

```
$scope.MainArray=[];
```

and then use it in your save object function.

Comment: Hi Jigar, thanks for your answer. I have already declared that in my HomeController.js. Just to show the array I have initialized here.

Comment: So why are you re-declare it inside save object function ?

Answer (score 0):

Here, you only send the item to your backend:

```
var promiseObj= $http.post('My_Url',{expectedItem: item});
```

and here you expecting it to be changed:

```
$scope.newItem.dataList= item.dataList
$scope.newItem.LatestComment = item.LatestComment;
$scope.newItem.CreatedDate = item.CreatedDate;
```

Your answer is contained in the **data** object, not the **item**. `item` won't ever change this way.

Comment: the item object holds all the data that is to be saved . After saving i get only Id in **data** object. And to push it in the array , am just assinging all the values from **item** and **data** to **newItem** object.

Comment: Check for typos: for example, you have "dataList" and "DataList" - it's impossible that it works, unless you pasted something else than you actually have in the code. Also, there's no need for the "newItem" to be in $scope - a simple var declared in the "success" function would be sufficient.